# Halloween items

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

After the Treehouse of Horror event is done, I assume we get to keep our special items. What happens to our GOO collecting, and buildings/missions that produce GOO? I'm assuming a similar thing as the Whacking Day event, but I wasn't playing the game back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to convert it to cash. 4 goo equals 300 dollars, at least from buildings. Missions seem to have all just turned to cash